# Infinite loop after logging in with Keycloak behind a reverse proxy

Tags: docker, ssl, nginx, https, keycloak

**My scenario**

I have a server with IP x.x.x.x

My web application is running on port 8083 of the server.

Keycloak (deployed with docker) is running on port 8080 of the server.

I want to setup nginx so that when I visit `my-website.com`, it will redirect to my web app at `x.x.x.x:8083`, and when I visit `my-website.com/auth`, it will redirect to Keycloak at `x.x.x.x:8080`. I also use SSL for my website.

Here's my nginx ssl.conf file

```
upstream upstream_auth {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name my-website.com www.my-website.com;
    return 301 https://my-website.com;
}

server {

    listen       443;
    ssl          on;
    server_name my-website.com;

    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/my-website.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/my-website.key;

    ssl_protocols        TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparams.pem;

    keepalive_timeout    60;
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout  10m;


    root /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT/;
    client_max_body_size 50M;

    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:8083/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
    location /auth/{
       proxy_pass  http://upstream_auth;
       proxy_http_version 1.1;
       proxy_set_header URI_REQUEST_ORIGIN $request_uri;
       proxy_set_header Host            $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      #proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;

      proxy_set_header Connection **;
      proxy_set_header Proxy **;
    }
}
```

**My problem:**

When I visit `my-website.com/auth`, it takes me to [keycloak landing page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/meB2Y.png) (as I expect). Then I click on Administrator Console and then login to Master Realm of Keycloak, the browser seems to stuck in an infinite loop of `https://my-website.com/auth/admin/master/console/` and `https://my-website.com/auth/admin/master/console/#state={constantly-changing-string}&session_state=xxx&code={another-constantly-changing-string}`.

I've been searching for solution and there seems to be many reasons that may cause this happen.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just figured out how to fix my issue.

I add  the following line in my docker-compose for Keycloak, and everything works fine now:

```
 PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING: 'true'
```

As written in https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/keycloak/:

> When running Keycloak behind a proxy, you will need to enable proxy
>   address forwarding.
>
> ```
> docker run -e PROXY_ADDRESS_FORWARDING=true jboss/keycloak
> ```

Not sure why it works tho. If anyone can explain, please do. I would like to understand my problem here.